# Java mail API not working in android

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I added the three jar files to java build path,added Internet uses permission all setted good to go.! I putted a button in my main page, whenever i click on this button an intent to this java mail class to work, and the email have to send to the corresponding users. But when i click on the button It suddenly shows up that Appplication stopped working..!! One thing is that i didnt used any layout for this java mail class. that you will understand when you see the below code. it cause i want to send the message automatically.!! what to do.?? help me guys.?? Thank You.!!

```
package;


import java.util.Date; 
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 


public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 


  private String _user;
  private String _pass;

 private String to1,to2,to3,to4,to5; // here i putted my recepients name
  private String[] _to = {to1,to2,to3,to4,to5}; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject = "HELLO";
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public Mail() { 

    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 



    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  } 

  // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post the code that calls this class (likely your `Activity`).  There are some common problems that could cause this, like the [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

I wrote some working Android mail code based on the same `javax.mail` code, and it works correctly.  Here's the code:

```
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            /*
             * Send email in a background thread
             */
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // retrieve the configuration values from preferences
                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(theActivity);
                    String destinationAddress = preferences.getString("email_destination_address", theActivity.getString(R.string.default_email_destination_address));
                    String senderAddress = preferences.getString("email_from", theActivity.getString(R.string.default_email_sender_address));
                    String senderPassword = preferences.getString("email_password", theActivity.getString(R.string.default_email_sender_password));
                    String smtpServer = preferences.getString("email_server", theActivity.getString(R.string.default_smtp_server));

                    Mail m = new Mail(senderAddress, senderPassword);

                    String[] toArr = { destinationAddress };
                    m.setHost(smtpServer);
                    m.setTo(toArr);
                    m.setFrom(EMAIL_USERNAME);
                    m.setSubject(getString(R.string.email_subject, barcode));
                    m.setBody(getString(R.string.email_body));

                    try {
                        ArrayList<String> filesToSend = theAdapter.getFilenames();

                        for (String file : filesToSend)
                        {
                            m.addAttachment(file);
                        }

                        if (m.send()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "EMAIL SENT SUCCESSFULLY");
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "EMAIL NOT SENT");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Could not send email", e);
                    }

                }
            });
            t.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.email_sending), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            theActivity.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Note:  if I were writing this code today I might use an `AsyncTask` instead of a Thread, but either are considered valid.

Comment: Actually i want the users to enter thier own email recepients and also username and password.!! Users may use different emails like gmail,yahoo,redifff...etc.!! So how to set up all these .??

Comment: i mean the SMTP for all these mail services..//!! Do u got what i am saying.!! i want to let the user to enter the recepients mail address with his username and password., and the app have to get all these values and have to send the email automatically.By just clicking in the button.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the rest of the code for getters and setters. See the comment at the bottom of your code:

```
// more of the getters and setters …..
```

You need to add the following in place of that comment:

```
/**
 * METHOD TO SET THE "TO" STRING ARRAY
 * @param toArr
 */
public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
    this._to = toArr;
}

/**
 * METHOD TO GET THE "TO" STRING ARRAY
 * @return
 */
public String[] getTo() {
    return _to;
} 

/**
 * METHOD TO SET THE "FROM" FIELD FOR THE MESSAGE
 * @param string
 */
public void setFrom(String string) {
    this._from = string;
}

/**
 * METHOD TO GET THE "FROM" FIELD FOR THE MESSAGE
 * @return
 */
public String getFrom() {
    return _from;
} 

/**
 * METHOD TO SET THE MESSAGE SUBJECT
 * @param string
 */
public void setSubject(String string) {
    this._subject = string;
} 

/**
 * METHOD TO GET THE MESSAGE SUBJECT
 * @return
 */
public String getSubject() {
    return _subject;
}
```

This should work. The next obstacle you will face will be what DShaw mentions below about the  [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), which can be fixed by either using this [post](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/02/22/android-strictmode-networkonmainthreadexception/) to not check StrictMode, but the better option is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) as is discussed in [this](http://javapapers.com/android/android-email-app-with-gmail-smtp-using-javamail/) post.

[EDIT] I also had a problem with proguard! If none of the above works, try to disable proguard to see if it works then.

Hope this helps.