# Android app not signing in to twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I used the all the codes correctly and my twitter connecting android app working fine. But when it shows up the sign in button, i clicked on this button several times but nothing happens. It loading and again coming back to the same page.!
please help me guys.! Thanks in advance..!!
My Main.java class given below :

```
 public class Main extends Activity {
        // Constants
        /**
         * Register your here app https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and get your
         * consumer key and secret
         * */
        static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "";
        static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "";
    
        // Preference Constants
        static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
        static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
        static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
        static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";
    
        static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = " OAuthTwitter://myTweet";
    
        // Twitter oauth urls
        static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
        static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
        static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    
        // Login button
        Button btnLoginTwitter;
        // Update status button
        Button btnUpdateStatus;
        // Logout button
        Button btnLogoutTwitter;
        // EditText for update
        EditText txtUpdate;
        // lbl update
        TextView lblUpdate;
        TextView lblUserName;
    
        // Progress dialog
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
    
        // Twitter
        private static Twitter twitter;
        private static RequestToken requestToken;
        
        // Shared Preferences
        private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
        
        // Internet Connection detector
        private ConnectionDetector cd;
        
        // Alert Dialog Manager
        AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            
            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    
            // Check if Internet present
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(Main.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                        "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                return;
            }
            
            // Check if twitter keys are set
            if(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0 || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0){
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(Main.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens", "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                return;
            }
    
            // All UI elements
            btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
            btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
            btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
            txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
            lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
            lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);
    
            // Shared Preferences
            mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                    "MyPref", 0);
    
            /**
             * Twitter login button click event will call loginToTwitter() function
             * */
            btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // Call login twitter function
                    loginToTwitter();
                }
            });
    
            /**
             * Button click event to Update Status, will call updateTwitterStatus()
             * function
             * */
            btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Call update status function
                    // Get the status from EditText
                    String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();
    
                    // Check for blank text
                    if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                        // update status
                        new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
                    } else {
                        // EditText is empty
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please enter status message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            });
    
            /**
             * Button click event for logout from twitter
             * */
            btnLogoutTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // Call logout twitter function
                    logoutFromTwitter();
                }
            });
    
            /** This if conditions is tested once is
             * redirected from twitter page. Parse the uri to get oAuth
             * Verifier
             * */
            if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
                if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                    // oAuth verifier
                    String verifier = uri
                            .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
    
                    try {
                        // Get the access token
                        AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                                requestToken, verifier);
    
                        // Shared Preferences
                        Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    
                        // After getting access token, access token secret
                        // store them in application preferences
                        e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                        e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                                accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                        // Store login status - true
                        e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                        e.commit(); // save changes
    
                        Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());
    
                        // Hide login button
                        btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
                        // Show Update Twitter
                        lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        
                        // Getting user details from twitter
                        // For now i am getting his name only
                        long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                        User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                        String username = user.getName();
                        
                        // Displaying in xml ui
                        lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Check log for login errors
                        Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
    
        }
    
        /**
         * Function to login twitter
         * */
        private void loginToTwitter() {
            // Check if already logged in
            if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                Configuration configuration = builder.build();
                
                TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
                twitter = factory.getInstance();
    
                try {
                    requestToken = twitter
                            .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                    this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // user already logged into twitter
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Function to update status
         * */
        class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    
            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }
    
            /**
             * getting Places JSON
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
                String status = args[0];
                try {
                    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                    
                    // Access Token 
                    String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                    // Access Token Secret
                    String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");
                    
                    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
                    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);
                    
                    // Update status
                    twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);
                    
                    Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    // Error in updating status
                    Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }
    
            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
             * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
             * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        // Clearing EditText field
                        txtUpdate.setText("");
                    }
                });
            }
    
        }
    
        /**
         * Function to logout from twitter
         * It will just clear the application shared preferences
         * */
        private void logoutFromTwitter() {
            // Clear the shared preferences
            Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
            e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
            e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
            e.commit();
    
            // After this take the appropriate action
            // I am showing the hiding/showing buttons again
            // You might not needed this code
            btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lblUserName.setText("");
            lblUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
            btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    
        /**
         * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
         * fetched from Shared Preferences
         * */
        private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
            // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
            return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
        }
    
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        }
```

The image given below.

[image]

Comment: without logs and code...really difficult to find solution!!

Comment: I addedd the code. Please take a look.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your DDMS, you should have `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception in your app. That is because `requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);` issued a http request on main UI thread. You should implement a AsyncTask class to handle the request.

AsyncTask class DOC: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Alvin, you're handling the Twitter callback in the wrong place. The callback code should not be in your activity's `onCreate(Bundle)` method. Assuming you've followed a tutorial something like this...

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/sending-a-tweet/

... where you've added an intent-filter in your app manifest for your `Main` activity to catch the callback, the callback code should then be in your activity's `onNewIntent(Intent)` method.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I wil check it out that for sure.!! If you doont mind check my other questions please.!! The link given below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055126/facebook-status-update-automatically-android?noredirect=1#comment31659090_21055126

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052456/java-mail-api-not-working-in-android/21052628?noredirect=1#21052628

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037051/automatically-update-status-to-facebook?noredirect=1#comment31651467_21037051

Comment: If you dont mind , can you please add the answer code here. by editting my android code.

Comment: Please note that in the link http://blog.blundell-apps.com/sending-a-tweet/ and in almost all blogs\posts\stackoverflow answers, the term application type as browser is used.Its now outdated as in this thread: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/282